# TextView is blank when set using setText()

Tags: android, textview

`Textview` (`tt`) is not displaying text set by `setText()`. I am not able to see output in `TextView`. I have tried using a `Toast` and `setText()` but in both case I am getting blank output. Why am I getting this blank output?

```
package com.divik.ds;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;
String x,y,z,xx;
TextView tt;
Button btn;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     ed2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     ed3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
     tt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
     btn=(Button)   findViewById(R.id.button1);
   try{
   x=(ed1.getText().toString());
   y=(ed2.getText().toString());
   z=(ed3.getText().toString());
   xx=x+""+y+""+z;
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

 }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        try{
     tt.setText(xx);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Toast.makeText(this,xx,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

Here is xml code. I have used 3 `EditText`s , 4 `TextView`s and 1 `Button`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter Date"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >


</EditText>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter month"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >


</EditText>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter year"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >


    </EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

    android:textSize="30dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code instead:-

```
package com.divik.ds;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;
String x,y,z,xx;
TextView tt;
Button btn;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     ed2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     ed3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
     tt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
     btn=(Button)   findViewById(R.id.button1);
     btn.setOnClickListener(this);

 }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

try{
   x=(ed1.getText().toString());
   y=(ed2.getText().toString());
   z=(ed3.getText().toString());
   xx=x+""+y+""+z;
   tt.setText(xx);

   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }



Toast.makeText(this,xx,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

Comment: Do let me know if this code is not working. And if its working then mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @RisingSun Make sure you understand ***why*** it's working because that will benefit you more in the future than just having it working *now*.

Comment: yes ..its not working earlier because first onCreate is executed and ed1 is not having value at that time that's why i was getting an empty value without any error. Now we have placed it in the function(onClick) which is exectued only after pressing button.So till the time button is pressed we have also a Editable format value in ed1 which is converted to integer in this function  ...right??

Answer (score 3):

Since

```
x=(ed1.getText().toString());
y=(ed2.getText().toString());
z=(ed3.getText().toString());
xx=x+""+y+""+z;
```

are in `onCreate()` they will be empty when the `Activity` first starts.

You can fix it by putting those lines in your `onClick()`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try{
        x= ed1.getText().toString();
        y= ed2.getText().toString();
        z= ed3.getText().toString();
        xx=x+""+y+""+z;
        tt.setText(xx);
     } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }

    Toast.makeText(this,xx,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```